# How can I create a paint bitmap?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, save

Ok so this is my full CanvasView where I don't have created bitmap and I really don't know how can do that. If you understand it and if you can help me please do it. Thank you in advance! The save function is in FirstActivity and it said the bitmap is null.

```
public class CanvasView extends View{

private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH/2;
Paint erasePaint = new Paint();
Paint paint = new Paint();
Path path = new Path();

float lastTouchX,lastTouchY;

AlertDialog.Builder alert;

RectF ovalRectangle = new RectF();
RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

MyRectangle myRectangle;
MyOval myOval;
MyCircle myCircle;
MyFreehand myFreehand; 
MyLine myLine;
MyEraser myEraser;

List<MyEraser> eraserList = new ArrayList<MyEraser>();
List<MyLine> lineList = new ArrayList<MyLine>();
List<MyFreehand> freehandList  = new ArrayList<MyFreehand>();
List<MyCircle> circleList = new ArrayList<MyCircle>();
List<MyOval> ovalList = new ArrayList<MyOval>();
List<MyRectangle> rectangleList = new ArrayList<MyRectangle>();



public boolean dashedLine = false;
public DashPathEffect dashEffect = new DashPathEffect(new float[]{20,30}, 0);
private Paint mBitmapPaint;
private Bitmap mBitmap; 

public String textValue;

public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);


    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) 
    {
        turnOffHardwareAcc();
    }


    erasePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    //erasePaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

    erasePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    erasePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    erasePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    erasePaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    paint.setTextSize(34);

    setMode(7);//default = 7 - free hand;

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    /* input dialog*/

     //setInputDialog();

}
EditText input;
public void setInputDialog(){

    alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    alert.setTitle("Title");
    alert.setMessage("Write text");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    input = new EditText(getContext());
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
         textValue= input.getText().toString();
         Toast.makeText(getContext(), textValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      // Do something with value!
      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
      }
    });

    //alert.show();

}

public void setDashLine(){

    dashedLine = true;
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setPathEffect(dashEffect);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
}

public void setNormalLine(){
    //paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    dashedLine = false;

    paint.setPathEffect(null);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setPathEffect(null);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
}

@TargetApi(11)
public void turnOffHardwareAcc() // to enable dashed lines
{

    this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}

//public void setPaint(int color,)

@TargetApi(11)
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if(dashedLine){
        paint.setPathEffect(dashEffect);
    }
    else {
        paint.setPathEffect(null);
    }

    if(bitmap!=null){

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
         for(MyCircle circle:circleList){// draw circles

             myCanvas.drawCircle(getCircleMidPointX(circle.firstX, circle.lastX),getCircleMidPointY(circle.firstY, circle.lastY),circle.radius,myPaint);
         }

    }


    for(MyLine line:lineList){ //draw lines
         if(dashedLine)
             line.paint.setPathEffect(dashEffect);
         else
             line.paint.setPathEffect(null);
            canvas.drawLine(line.xStart, line.yStart, line.xEnd, line.yEnd, line.paint);
      }

     for(MyCircle circle:circleList){// draw circles

         canvas.drawCircle(getCircleMidPointX(circle.firstX, circle.lastX),getCircleMidPointY(circle.firstY, circle.lastY),circle.radius,paint);
     }

     for(MyOval oval:ovalList){
         if(dashedLine)
             oval.paint.setPathEffect(dashEffect);
         else oval.paint.setPathEffect(null);

           ovalRectangle.set(oval.getX1(),oval.getY1(),oval.getX2(),oval.getY2());
           canvas.drawOval(ovalRectangle, oval.paint);
     }

     for(MyRectangle rectangle:rectangleList){
         if(dashedLine)
             rectangle.paint.setPathEffect(dashEffect);
         else rectangle.paint.setPathEffect(null);

           canvas.drawRect(rectangle.getX1(),rectangle.getY1(),rectangle.getX2(),rectangle.getY2(),rectangle.paint);
     }  

     for(MyEraser e:eraserList){
            canvas.drawPath(e.p,erasePaint);
            invalidate();
     }
     if(textValue!= null)
         canvas.drawText(textValue, xStart, yStart, paint);
     canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
     //path.reset();

}

final OnTouchListener drawLineListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        FirstActivity.ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              myLine = new MyLine();
              myLine.xStart = event.getX();
              myLine.yStart = event.getY();

            return true;

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            myLine.xEnd = event.getX();
            myLine.yEnd = event.getY();
            invalidate();
            lineList.add(myLine); 
            break;

          default:
            Log.d("mock it up", "Unknown touch event  " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
};

final OnTouchListener drawDashedLineListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        FirstActivity.ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             return true;

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;

          default:
            Log.d("mock it up", "Unknown touch event  " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
};

final OnTouchListener drawCircleListener = new OnTouchListener(){

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        FirstActivity.ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();



        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           //  path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
              Toast.makeText(getContext(), "action down - circle",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              myCircle = new MyCircle();
              myCircle.firstX = eventX;
              myCircle.firstY = eventY;

            // There is no end point yet, so don't waste cycles invalidating.
            return true;

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            myCircle.lastX = eventX;
            myCircle.lastY = eventY;

            myCircle.radius = getRadius(myCircle.firstX,myCircle.firstY,myCircle.lastX,myCircle.lastY);

            circleList.add(myCircle);

            invalidate();
            break;

          default:
            Log.d("mock it up", "Unknown touch event  " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }
  return true;
    }

};

final OnTouchListener drawOvalListener = new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            FirstActivity.ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

            switch (event.getAction()) {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                myOval = new MyOval();
                myOval.setX1(event.getX());
                myOval.setY1(event.getY());
                // There is no end point yet, so don't waste cycles invalidating.
                return true;

              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                  myOval.setX2(event.getX());
                  myOval.setY2(event.getY());

                  invalidate();
                  ovalList.add(myOval);

              default:
                Log.d("mock it up", "Unknown touch event  " + event.toString());
                return false;
            }

        }
    };

final OnTouchListener drawRectangleListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            FirstActivity.ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

            switch (event.getAction()) {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                  myRectangle = new MyRectangle();
                  myRectangle.setX1(event.getX());
                  myRectangle.setY1(event.getY());
                return true;

              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                  myRectangle.setX2(event.getX());
                  myRectangle.setY2(event.getY());
                  invalidate();
                  rectangleList.add(myRectangle);

                break;

              default:
                Log.d("mock it up", "Unknown touch event  " + event.toString());
                return false;
            }


            return true;
        }
};

final OnTouchListener eraseListener = new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    //  erasePaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        //FirstActivity.ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             myEraser = new MyEraser();
              lastTouchX = event.getX();
              lastTouchY = event.getY();
              myEraser.mouseDown(event.getX(), event.getY());
              return true;

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
              resetDirtyRect(event.getX(),event.getY());
              int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
              for(int i=0;i<historySize;i++){
                  float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                  float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                  expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);

                  myEraser.mouseUp(historicalX, historicalY);
            }
              myEraser.mouseUp(event.getX(), event.getY());
              eraserList.add(myEraser);
             break;

          default:
            Log.d("mock it up", "Unknown touch event  " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }



        invalidate(
                (int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

            lastTouchX = event.getX();
            lastTouchY = event.getY();
       return true;
    }
};

final OnTouchListener drawFreeHandListener = new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        FirstActivity.ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             // path.reset();
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            lastTouchX = eventX;
            lastTouchY = eventY;
            // There is no end point yet, so don't waste cycles invalidating.
            return true;

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Start tracking the dirty region.
            resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);

            // When the hardware tracks events faster than they are delivered, the
            // event will contain a history of those skipped points.
            int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
            for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
              float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
              float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
              expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
              path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
            }

            // After replaying history, connect the line to the touch point.
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            //path.reset();
            break;

          default:
            Log.d("mock it up", "Unknown touch event  " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }

        // Include half the stroke width to avoid clipping.
        invalidate(
            (int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
            (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
            (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
            (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;

        return true;
    }
};

float xStart,yStart;
final OnTouchListener textListener = new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        FirstActivity.ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

    //  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "add some text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              //
              setInputDialog();
              xStart = event.getX();
              yStart = event.getY();
              alert.show();
            break;

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //  setInputDialog();
                  break;

          default:
            Log.d("mock it up", "Unknown touch event  " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }


        return true;
    }
};

/**
 * Called when replaying history to ensure the dirty region includes all
 * points.
 */
private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) {
  if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) {
    dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
  } else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) {
    dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
  }
  if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) {
    dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
  } else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) {
    dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
  }
}

/**
 * Resets the dirty region when the motion event occurs.
 */
private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {

  // The lastTouchX and lastTouchY were set when the ACTION_DOWN
  // motion event occurred.
  dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
  dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
  dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
  dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
}


public void setMode(int mode){
    switch(mode){
    case 1://draw line
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "draw line", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setOnTouchListener(drawLineListener);
        break;
    case 2://draw dashed line
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "dashed line", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case 3:// draw circle
        setOnTouchListener(drawCircleListener);
        break;
    case 4: //draw oval
        setOnTouchListener(drawOvalListener);
        break;
    case 5: //draw rectangle
        setOnTouchListener(drawRectangleListener);
        break;
    case 6: //erase
        setOnTouchListener(eraseListener);
        break;
    case 7: //free-hand
        setOnTouchListener(drawFreeHandListener);
        break;
    case 8:
        setOnTouchListener(textListener);
        break;
    }
}

private Bitmap bitmap;
private Canvas myCanvas;
public Paint myPaint;

public void setImage(Bitmap b){
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "set Bitmap",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    myCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    myPaint = new Paint();
    myPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    myPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    myPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);

    invalidate();
}

public void changeColor(int color){
    paint = new Paint(paint);
    paint.setColor(color);
    //myPaint.setColor(color);
}

public float getRadius(float x1,float y1,float x2,float y2){
      float r = (float) (Math.sqrt((double)(Math.pow((y2-y1), 2.0)+Math.pow((x2-x1), 2.0)))/2);
      return r;
  }

public float getCircleMidPointX(float x1,float x2){
      return (x1+x2)/2;
  }

public float getCircleMidPointY(float y1,float y2){
      return (y1+y2)/2;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the Bitmap in place, right there where you are saving it to file. Then you have to create your own Canvas based on the bitmap and pass it to draw method of your View. Something like this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.tools:
    ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
    return true;
    case R.id.import_pics:
    getPhotos();
    return true;
    case R.id.save:
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(theView.getWidth(),theView.getHeight,Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        theView.draw(canvas);
        storeImage(bitmap);
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
    return true;
    case R.id.trash:
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Move the drawing code to draw method.

I guess this is what you're asking about. The question is not exactly the clearest one.